# how to display value of javascript variables in chrome after javascript error

Tags: javascript

AT work I am working on a Perl/CGI script running under the Google Chrome browser that generates javascript code to dynamically update the displayed page.

Unfortunately my script stops (ie. it dies !!) with the following type of error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

the offending line is

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = img;
```

How do I display the value of the javascript variable `id` with Google Chrome ?

I have done much searching on this topic and nothing has been helpful so far.
I have been exploring the developer tools window but can't seem to find anything to display the value of a JS  variable

Comment: This will likely also help: [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/218196)

Comment: Make sure you have a look at all the answers on the linked duplicate - there's a lot of info in there.

Comment: I have been looking everywhere and I am desperate ! How do I do this under Chrome ?

Comment: console.log(id) will print the values of id in chrome console

Comment: console.log(id) will do the trick! ;) Put this in your code and after that in execution time open chrome console to see the result.